# Searching Salesforce Knowledge via API

Tags: api, knowledge, heroku

I want to present a bunch of Salesforce Knowledge articles to the anonymous public via our own interface, but from what I can see there is no standalone knowledge interface that I can use (it needs to be communities from what I can see).

Therefore, I'm looking at using my own front end and Heroku Connect, or the Salesforce API.

Question is, is there a way to use the Knowledge Search directly, or do I need to provide my own search against the data in Heroku Connect/Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce exposes the following endpoints that can be used to access Knowledge Base articles (there are others but these are the one's I have found easiest to use):

> **[parameterizedSearch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search_parameterized.htm)**
>
> Executes a simple RESTful search using parameters instead of a SOSL clause. Indicate parameters in a URL in the GET method. Or, use POST for more complex JSON searches.

**Example:**

To run a parameterized search of your knowledge articles, you can use the following query (You will need to update the language to the language your knowledge base is in if it isn't english):

`https://yourdomain.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/parameterizedSearch/?q=searchterm&sobject=KnowledgeArticleVersion&KnowledgeArticleVersion.where=language='en_US'+and+publishStatus='online'`

> **[Articles List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_knowledge_support_artlist.htm)**
>
> Get a page of online articles for the given language and category through either search or query.

**Example:**

`https://yourdomain.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/support/knowledgeArticles?q=searchterm`

Comment: `https://yourdomain.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/parameterizedSearch/?q=searchterm&sobject=KnowledgeArticleVersion&KnowledgeArticleVersion.where=language='en_US'+and+publishStatus='online'` 

seems to return 

`Unable to parse constraint:Bind variables only allowed in Apex code`?